# Does CWnd::Create spawn a new thread?

Tags: c++, mfc

H,

I have a old MFC application with a class that inherits from CWnd. I was talking to the original author, who stated that Cwnd::Create() makes a new thread. I however can not find any reference to this in the MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yhc9kx4.aspx

Can anyone confirm that when Cwnd is Create() is called there is a new thread started. A link to some documentation explaining it would be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: I think he was getting confused with CWinThread.

Comment: Maybe. It was something he wrote about 8+ years ago and I've been adding functionality too. Considering I struggle to remember what I did last month I was surprised at what he remembered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft makes the source of MFC available [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs046sh0.aspx), so you can examine the MFC source code yourself and see exactly what it does.  See C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp for the implementation of CWnd::Create and it's clear that no new thread is created.

Comment: Thanks I was not aware that Icode grab the code. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.